# The audio on compressed videos is distorted in xamarin forms ios

Tags: ios, audio, video, xamarin.forms, compression

We are using captured video functionality in my application xamarin forms ios. After the captured the video we are compressing the video and uploaded it to the webserver. The audio on compressed videos is distorted. Here is the video compression code:

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputPath);
        string outputPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), fileName + ".mp4");

        TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        var outputURL = new NSUrl(outputPath);

        NSError error = new NSError();

        using (AVAsset asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(inputPath)))
        using (AVAssetExportSession export = new AVAssetExportSession(asset, AVAssetExportSessionPreset.MediumQuality))
        {
            export.OutputFileType = AVFileType.Mpeg4;
            export.ShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;
            export.OutputUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(outputURL.ToString());

            NSFileManager.DefaultManager.Remove(outputURL, out error);

                export.ExportTaskAsync();
                Stream exportStream = File.OpenRead(tmp);
```

How to resolve this in xamarin forms ios?

Comment: Did you try `AVAssetExportSessionPreset.HighestQuality` instead of `AVAssetExportSessionPreset.MediumQuality` ?

Comment: Try another `OutputFileType ` ,Mpeg4  type may cost the video quality .